# Change color text and font weight on click

Tags: jquery, onclick

this is my snippet code:

http://jsfiddle.net/STqCF/115/

I need  the text turns red , with font-weight bold when i click over the link

How to do it with jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean click over or mouse over?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/STqCF/116/

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your issue here, One line of fix and css added :

http://jsfiddle.net/STqCF/120/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css class like this:

```
.test a
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:Red;
}​
```

And then add this to the 'show hide' binding:

```
    $('.accordion').on('show hide', function(e){
    $(e.target).siblings('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle i').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down icon-arrow-up', 200);

    $(this).toggleClass('test');
});
```